# Image of Diffeomorphism to $R^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If a diffeomorphism $F$ is defined by $F:V\rightarrow \Bbb R^n$, does this mean $F(V)=\Bbb R^n$ ? My textbook keeps explicitly using $F(V)$ but I don't understand how this could be anything other than $\Bbb R^n$ given that $F$ is a diffeomorphism (and thus bijective). Could someone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, if $F$ is a diffeomorphism then $F(V)=\mathbb{R}^n$. The author MIGHT be using $F(V)$ to emphasize it's the codomain/range of $F$ but either one is okay.

Comment: Some authors are lazy, too, and really mean $F(V) = U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. the diffeomorphism $F$ has a 'friendly' Euclidean image, or that its image lies in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and instead of defining this subspace, they use the whole product space as the codomain. I guess it depends on the context of $F$...